# Decoding Caesar Cipher with Bruteforce

Tags: python, cryptography, brute-force

I am working on the decoding part of the Ceaser Cphier which is as known Bruteforce. I am trying to catch the encrypted word as a string. But even when I use the str it does not convert. The issue is wit the variable plaincode. I used print to see if there is anything in it but the output is none. Can you help please?

```
 def main():
#take user word and pass it to the function to encrypt it
  letters='ABCDEFGHIJLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
  userinput=str(input("Enter the word to encrypt:"))
  UserInput = userinput.upper()
  print("You entered:",UserInput)
  key=int(input("Enter the key shift:"))
  sendtoincrypt(UserInput,key)
global key #send the word for incryption
  
def sendtoincrypt(UserInput,key):
  coded_char=[]
  newcode=0
  for each in UserInput:
    x=ord(each) #ord retrive the number of the ASCII of the word
    newcode=x+key
    coded_char.append(newcode)
  displaycodednum(coded_char)
    
def displaycodednum(coded_char):
  print("The coded number is:", coded_char)
  processcodedword(coded_char)

def processcodedword (coded_char):
  coded_word=[]

  # for i, c in enumerate('test'):
   #print i, c
  for each, c in enumerate(coded_char):
    y=chr(c)
    coded_word.append(y)
  displaycodedword(coded_word)

def displaycodedword(coded_word):
  print("The coded word is:",*coded_word, sep='')
  plaincode=print(*coded_word, sep='')
  str(plaincode) #-------------------------<< trying to convert it to text
  print("Converted to string:", plaincode) #--<<The out put is "None" which means its not converted...why?
  dycrypt(plaincode)

def dycrypt(plaincode):
  str(plaincode)
  decoded_word=[]
  for each, c in enumerate(plaincode): #<<---The error is here "not iratable ...because its not converted to text
    z=chr(c)
    decoded_word.append(z)
  displaydecodedword(decoded_word)

def displaydecodedword(decoded_word):
  print("The coded word is:",*decoded_word, sep='')
  plaincode=print(*decoded_word, sep='')
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to brute force a Caesar cipher is to take the encrypted text and try every one of the 25 possible keys.  It is called "running down the alphabet".

```
NBCM CM UH YRUGJFY
nbcm cm uh yrugjfy
ocdn dn vi zsvhkgz
pdeo eo wj atwilha
qefp fp xk buxjmib
rfgq gq yl cvyknjc
sghr hr zm dwzlokd
this is an example
uijt jt bo fybnqmf
vjku ku cp gzcorng
wklv lv dq hadpsoh
xlmw mw er ibeqtpi
ymnx nx fs jcfruqj
znoy oy gt kdgsvrk
aopz pz hu lehtwsl
bpqa qa iv mfiuxtm
cqrb rb jw ngjvyun
drsc sc kx ohkwzvo
estd td ly pilxawp
ftue ue mz qjmybxq
guvf vf na rknzcyr
hvwg wg ob sloadzs
iwxh xh pc tmpbeat
jxyi yi qd unqcfbu
kyzj zj re vordgcv
lzak ak sf wpsehdw
mabl bl tg xqtfiex
nbcm cm uh yrugjfy
```

You then have to pick out the correct decryption from the possibilities listed.

Comment: Thankyou @rossum - That what I am intending to do. but the generated text is not converted to text. as you can see on my print (convert to text)....if you try the code it will display None...And I don't know why

Comment: Break your code up into smaller pieces and test each piece separately.  That will help you see where the problem is, and concentrate on that piece of code.  I'm afraid my Python is very bad.